# Clear Data - Synchronized data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Is it possible to clear Synchronized data extension? I want to clear all data and resynch as I want to remove some fields from Synchronized data extension.

Comment: Yes, It's possible.

Comment: If you want to remove some field from Sync DE, Go to Sync Object(Contact Builder ), click on Edit field, Un-check those fields and refresh the Object.

Comment: Thanks Vikas, when I go to Data Extensions in Contact Builder and open any Synchronized data extension the Clear Records and Add Records buttons are both disabled. Is there some access issue or am I missing anything?

Comment: Contact Builder>Data Sources>Click on Synchronized tab> Where you will get all the entities and Attributes> Type your sync DE name in Synchronized Entities search box, Later you can follow above steps

Answer (score 0):

As Vikas said, you can edit the field mapping and remove the sync - this will automatically remove them from the synchronized DE, albeit it might take some time to fully reflect.

In order to clear the data, you need to press this very small button shown below, although it sounds like you would do fine with simply deleting the fields? (i.e. removing the mapping)

[image]

Comment: how can we edit the field mapping and remove the sync?  When I go to edit fields, I can unmap only the optional fields.

Comment: You cannot delete the required fields I believe (you're thinking about the IDs right?) - they are required to build out the data model in Marketing Cloud.